# Join without association in HQL

Tags: hibernate, join, hql

Lets say I have two tables(A, B) like:

```
A {id, a, c}
B {id, b, c}
```

I have also their entities. I want to write an HQL so that the result set will be like (where A.c = B.c):

```
(a1, b1, c1)
(a2, b2, c2)
(a3, b3, c3)
...
```

Since `on` clauses are not supported by hibernate I am stuck and I don't know how to write the query.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You have to use the cross join notation:

```
from A as table_a , B as table_b
where table_a.c = table_b.c
```

Of course there is no way to implement outer joins in this manner, so you might have some trouble if that's your case.

For the analogous case with criteria refer to: [hibernate-criteria-joining-table-without-a-mapped-association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720502/hibernate-criteria-joining-table-without-a-mapped-association)

Comment: @II-BHIMA can I use left outer join in this secenario

Answer (score 3):

From Hibernate +5.1 version
Hibernate introduced Join queries similar to SQL joins between unrelated entities.

Ex.
Select a,b From Table a join Table b on a.id=b.id where condition

Comment: this is a very old question. add an explanation as to why this answer is better.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to make outer join you can make sub query and manage OR operation ( it works for me ).
it's make the query more complex and worst performant but works :-)

Answer (score 0):

if both the table are related to each other via foreign key then you can try this:

let:

A {id(primary key), a, c}
B {id(foreign key), b, c}

define a variable of type parent(A) with setter and getter in B class's pojo.after that you can write query in this way.
let it 'AA'

```
select tbl_b.a,tbl_a.a,tbl_b.b,tbl_a.b,tbl_b.c,tbl_a.c from B tbl_b inner join tbl_b.AA tbl_b
```