# Hibernate query criteria for join between 3 tables

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a sql query:

```
select * from A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id
INNER JOIN C
ON B.id = C.id
INNER JOIN D
ON C.id = D.id
where D.name = 'XYZ'
   and D.Sex = 'M'
```

I have been trying to come with hibernate query criteria for the above sql, but having problems. Could anybody help out.

Comment: what do you want as result? the A instances?

Comment: Speath, yes..i need instances from A

Comment: Hibernate is all about OR mapping.  No one knows what your entities look like simply by looking at your SQL.  It can be as simple as "from A where a.b.c.d.name='XYZ' and a.b.c.d.sex='M' " or unfeasible if you don't have proper relationships

Answer (score 5):

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(A.class, "a");
                    .createAlias("a.b", "b")
                    .createAlias("b.c", "c")
                    .createAlias("c.d", "d")
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("d.sex", "M"))
                    .add(Restrictions.eq("d.name", "XYZ"));
```

Comment: When we say session.createAlias("a.b",b)..would it create an inner join between A and B?

Comment: And how different is criteria.createAlias("a.b","b") is to just saying criteria.createAlias("b","b")

Comment: It wouldn't be different, however, the intial call to createCriteria gave an alias:  createCriteria(A.class, "a").  As a result and further reference to fields from the A instance need to use the "a." prefix.

Comment: Actually, I don't think they *must*, but at least they *can*. I find it clearer to asign an alias to each entity, even the root one. And yes, as the javadoc indicates, it creates an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

On your question you want to perform a *Cartesian Join*, and this is not supported by Criteria, although you can do it with HQL as show below. There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720502/hibernate-criteria-joining-table-without-a-mapped-association)

With HQL query you could do something like:

```
select a from 
   A a, 
   B b, 
   C c 
where 
   a.id = b.id and 
   c.id = b.id and 
   d.id = c.id and 
   d.name = 'XYZ' and 
   d.sex = 'M'
```

The query is used in a regular hibernate query:

```
Query query = session.createQuery(query); // <-- here you use the query above
List results = query.list();
```

Comment: I have to use hibernate's query criteria to do this. For ex- Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Dokument.class, "dokument");
c.createAlias("dokument.role", "role"); // inner join by default
c.createAlias("role.contact", "contact");
c.add(Restrictions.eq("contact.lastName", "Test"));
return c.list();