# Left join using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have two entity: `Issue` and `Issue_Tracker`. I am using Hibernate 3.6.

```
SELECT `issues`.`issue_id`,
       `issues`.`issue_raised_date`,
       `issues`.`issue_description`,
       `issue_tracker`.`tracker_status`
FROM `issues`
   LEFT JOIN  `issue_tracker` ON `issues`.`issue_id` = `issue_tracker`.`issue_id`
WHERE `issues`.`status`="Escalate To"
```

How to achieve this using Hibernate Criteria, and most Important, I have to use it for pagination.

**and My Dao is as follows to show the list of Issues in jqgrid**

> public List showHelpDeskIssues(DetachedCriteria dc, int from,
>   int size) {
>
> ```
> Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
>  try
>   {
>
>     Criteria criteria = dc.getExecutableCriteria(session);
>     criteria.setFirstResult(from);
>     criteria.setMaxResults(size);
>     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status","Escalate To"));
>
>     return criteria.list();
>   }
>   catch (HibernateException e)
>   {
>     e.printStackTrace();
>     throw e;
>   } }
> ```

For brief explanation please refer this question [how to show two tables data in jqgrid using struts2 - jqgrid plugin and hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211501/how-to-show-two-tables-data-in-jqgrid-using-struts2-jqgrid-plugin-and-hibernat) 
any help would be great.

Comment: You have probably misunderstood SQL join queries. Should be LEFT JOIN  `issue_tracker` ON `issues`.`issue_tracker_id` = `issue_tracker`.`id`

Comment: thanks...but right now this is not my area of concern.  I want to know how to achieve this using criteria

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can try the following

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Issues.class);
criteria.setFirstResult(from);
criteria.setMaxResults(size);
criteria.setFetchMode('parent.child', FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status", "Escalate To"));
List<Issues> list= criteria.list();
```

here parent is the property name in `Issues.java` and child is the property in `IssueTracker.java`.

Comment: thank for quick response, but i did not mapped these two pojo as one to many. Still it works and what is the property name?

Comment: have u done a many-to-one... these properties have to be mapped somhow for criteria to select them in the expected manner.

Comment: either use (issues) one-to-many (issue-tracker) or (issue-tracker) many-to-one (issue). with the 2nd approach you should create criteria on issue tracker and transform result to bean for issue.

Comment: ok.. I got it, one more question how what is property name you have mentioned in your answer

Comment: here you go.. http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/

Answer (score 8):

Well,

follow one sample...

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Issues.class);
crit.createAlias("otherClass", "otherClass");
crit.add(Restrictions.eq("otherClass.status", "Escalate To"));
List result = crit.list();
```

I think so this can to help!!

Comment: This saved me! This is the only example of `createAlias` that I could find.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out because this worked for me

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Issues.class, "issues");
criteria.setFetchMode("issues.issuetracker", FetchMode.JOIN);
criteria.createAlias("issues.issuetracker", "issuetracker");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("status","Escalate To"));
List list = criteria.list();
return list;
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: In Hibernate criteria, inner outer join and inner join are one and the same. Do not get confused.

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
 try{
     Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Issues.class, "issues");
     criteria.setFirstResult(from);
     criteria.setMaxResults(size);
     criteria.createAlias("issues.issuestracker", "issuestracker", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
     criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("issues.status", "Escalate To"));

     return criteria.list();
   }catch(HibernateException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       throw e;
     }
```

This should solve your issue. Let me know if you face any trouble.