# how to fetch records from a table through list?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have stored records from one Studegree table by Criteria list.

```
Criteria criteria= s. createCriteria(StuDegree.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("col_name","PSYEC"));
List<StuDegree> colname =(List<StuDegree>) criteria.list();
```

column names in StuDegree are colname,id,degree,dcode,sno. here id is common one to one relation to the StuPersonal table(id,name,gender,university). Now I need to group students records from StuPersonal table using colname list..Need help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Left join using hibernate criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215288/left-join-using-hibernate-criteria)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by hql very easily.

```
select stup from StuPersonal stup where studegree_id in (Select stud.id from Studegree stud  where col_name='PSYEC')
```

You can use your naming conventions

Comment: the above hql is to retreive directly form StuPersonal table but I need to map this Stupersonal table from the list i have created as collname, is there any idea?

Comment: mahes list all the columns in both the tables and also tell how you are connecting both the table ie relations between them also be clear what u want ?.You are creating the colname list from Studegree table and base on this list u want to retrieve the records from StuPersonal table so at least some thing should be common in between then so u can retrieve base on that common

Comment: Thanks Deepak,u got it.FRID is the column which is common for two tables.STuPersonal(sno,stu_name,gender,FRID) and StuDegree(sno,degree,dtype,regno,col_name).FRID ll be automatically included in StuDegree table. I used onetoone relationship here.enough?