# Hibernate Criteria Builder: How to filter by a nullable entity attribute?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

#### Scenario

I have an entity `Treatment` which has two FKs:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = true)
private Product product;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product2_id", nullable = true)
private Product product2;
```

This `Product` entity has a regular id attribute as PK.

#### What I want:

I want to find all treatments where any of the products' ids matches a given one, in native SQL it would be something like:

```
select t.id, product_id,product2_id, p1.category_id,p2.category_id
from Treatment t
left join product p1 on t.product_id=p1.id
left join product p2 on t.product2_id=p2.id
where p1.category_id=17 or p2.category_id=17
```

#### What I've done so far:

Given:

```
CriteriaQuery<Treatment> cr = cb.createQuery(Treatment.class);
Root<Treatment> root = cr.from(Treatment.class);
```

My attempt was:

```
if (category != null ) {
    Predicate predicate = cb.or( 
      cb.equal(root.get("product").get("category"), category),
      cb.equal(root.get("product2").get("category"), category)
    );
    predicateList.add(predicate);
}
```

but it did not work: it gets treatments where both products are not null and at least one of them matches the category condition.

The generated query was (after cleaning it to make it readable):

```
select 
  ...
from treatment t 
  cross join product p1 
  cross join product p2 
  where t.product_id=p1.id 
  and t.product2_id=p2.id 
  and (p1.category_id=17 or p2.category_id=17) 
order by t.id desc
```

Comment: You can perform the joins yourself using criteria as far as I know. `createAlias()` seems to be the way to go [according to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14215288/left-join-using-hibernate-criteria)

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I'm using Hibernate 5 and its *new* CriteriaBuilder API. The linked example generates warnings (*Deprecated* classes) as it is the old API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try building paths using `From#join`, where you can explicitly define join type, something like:

```
Predicate predicate = cb.or( 
  cb.equal(root.join("product", JoinType.LEFT).get("category"), category),
  cb.equal(root.join("product2", JoinType.LEFT).get("category"), category)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Predicate predicate = (root1, cq1, cb1) -> Specifications.where(
            cb1.equal(root1.get("product").get("category"), category)).or(
            cb1.equal(root1.get("product2").get("category"), category))
            .toPredicate(root, cb, cq);
```

Comment: I guess I'm missing something: Where should I put this lambda?

Comment: You are right, I did not clarify it. It returns predicate, so it should be placed inside of your predicate. (I updated the answer)

Comment: Sorry, but `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate` is not a functional interface in javax.persistence-api-2.2

Comment: I believe its @Alex's answer that is correct. The key is the Left Join

Comment: `.toPredicate(root, cb, cq);` pass your root, cb, cq you defined before