# show data in jqgrid column

Tags: hibernate, jqgrid, struts2, set, hibernate-mapping

I am using Struts 2.3.7, struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.5.0 and hibernate 3.6. I am using one to many mapping to join two entities. 
These Entities

Issue.java

```
    public class Issue implements Serializable
    {
    private Integer issue_id;
    private String  issue_description;
    private Date issue_raised_date;
    private Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker = new HashSet<Issue_Tracker>(0);

getter and setters
```

Issue_Tracker.java

```
public class Issue_Tracker implements Serializable
{  
     private Integer issue_id;
     private String assignedTo;
```

How to show this data in jqgrid in **assignedTo** column . My jqgrid is as follows :

```
<sjg:grid
    id="gridtable"
    caption="Issue-Summary"
    dataType="json"
    href="%{remoteurl}"
    pager="true"
    gridModel="gridModel"
    rowList="10,15,20"
    rowNum="15"
    rownumbers="true"
    reloadTopics="reloadGrid"
>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="issue_id"  id="issueId"  index="id" title="Issue-ID" formatter="integer"  sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="issue_description" index="id" title="Issue-Details"  sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="issue_raised_date" index="date" title="Issue-Date"  formatter="date"  sortable="false"/>

    <sjg:gridColumn name="issueTracker"  index="assigned" title="Assigned To"  sortable="false"/>
</sjg:grid>
```

But the output is as follows, 
[image]

How to show actual data instead of this object in **assignedTo** column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to show two tables data in jqgrid using struts2 - jqgrid plugin and hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211501/how-to-show-two-tables-data-in-jqgrid-using-struts2-jqgrid-plugin-and-hibernat)

Comment: Stop posting the same question over and over again.

Comment: And in which way they are different?

Comment: In this post ,did you notice what i am trying to ask, if no then please ask me for some additional comment otherwise do not waste your time, sorry

Comment: Ok, In my previous post I asked how to achieve one to many mapping and this current post I am asking how to show the data in jqgrid coloumn and check out the snapshot also

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that assignedTo is not multiple

Try this

Change

```
 private Set<Issue_Tracker> issueTracker = new HashSet<Issue_Tracker>(0);
```

To

```
  public  IssueTracker issueTracker;
```

And in your jsp page

Change

```
 <sjg:gridColumn name="issueTracker"  index="assigned" title="Assigned To"  sortable="false"/>
```

To

```
 <sjg:gridColumn name="issueTracker.assignedTo"  index="issueTracker.assigned" title="Assigned To"  sortable="false"/>
```

Comment: thanks but I got this error Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @ OneToMany, @ ManyToMany or @ CollectionOfElements

Comment: for your consideration I am using one to many mapping on Issue Entity so I have to use a collection of Issue_Tracker entity instead of Issue_Tracker object