# Equivalent Criteria query for below SQL query?

Tags: sql, hibernate-criteria

```
Select "answer" 
  from 'Details' 
 where "question" like 'child'
   AND "subject" IN (select "subject"
                   from 'Details' 
                   where "question" like 'child'
                     AND "answer" = "M" and "test" ="1");
```

Table Struture is :

```
Subject Test    Survey  Question              answer
----------------------------------------------------
rahul   1       one     childimmunization     Yes
rahul   1       one     childgender           M
Jyothi  1       one     childimmunization     No
Jyothi  1       one     childgender           F
Chikku  1       one     childimmunization     No
Chikku  1       one     childgender           M
```

Comment: Won't this always result in `answer = M` ?

Comment: No, in "answer" i want to get either YES or NO separately for Male ("M") and Female ("F"). But Now I need only for Male so in subquery I have make a condition as answer="M".

Comment: You are selecting the answer back again in outer query.

Comment: Yeah . Both inner query and outer query are there in same table with 2 different rows. In inner query I get subject name (Person name with gender as male) Now only for selected persons i need answer(either yes or No) which is another row.

Comment: Problems with the query: (1) `question like 'X'` is not the same as `question like 'X%'` and means exactly `question = 'X'`, (2) you have not stated that `test=1` in the outer query, so you can get results mixed up when several tests will be stored in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The most proper SQL-way to gather values from two or several rows into colums of single row is to *join table with itself* (one or more times). It is simpler and more convenient, than using subquery. 

   So, if you can create circular association from `Deatils` to `Details` in Hibernate - it would be the simplest solution. But I guess this is not possible, because Hibernate has known issue (and open task) with using same entity in join twice - details are [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=931249) and [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-879).
2. But according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720502/hibernate-criteria-joining-table-without-a-mapped-association) you still can try to use Hibernate `DetachedCriteria` as a subquery to make something very like your original SQL.

I will try to suggest this code, which was not tested though:

```
DetachedCriteria subjectsWithBoys = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Details.class)
  .setProjection(Property.forName("subject"))
  .add(Restrictions.eq("question", "childgender"))
  .add(Restrictions.eq("answer", "M"))
  .add(Restrictions.eq("test", "1"));

Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Details.class)
  .setProjection(Property.forName("answer"))
  .add(Property.forName("subject").in(subjectsWithBoys))
  .add(Restrictions.eq("question", "childimmunization"))
  .add(Restrictions.eq("test", "1"));
```

Hope you will make use of it easily and will not hit another open issue in Hibernate with such a trivial task.

Comment: I don't need SQL query , I need Equivalent Criteria query for my sql query. Note that my SQL query is working fine and There are no two tables there is only one table . On same table I written both inner and outer queries.  Thanks for your response . Hope you will get correct answer to my question

Comment: Oh, how could I miss the `hibernate-criteria` tag :) I have completely rewritten my answer. And by the way, I think, your original SQL query has problems and may 'work fine' just because the lack of testing.