# Criteria qyery for below SQL query? Both inner and outer query are for same table but for different rows

Tags: hibernate-criteria

```
Select "answer" 
  from 'Details' 
 where "question" like 'childimmunization'
   AND "subject" IN (select "subject"
                   from 'Details' 
                   where "question" like 'childgender'
                     AND "answer" = "M" and "test" ="1");
```

Table structure is :

```
Subject Test    Survey  Question              answer
----------------------------------------------------
rahul   1       one     childimmunization     Yes
rahul   1       one     childgender           M
Jyothi  1       one     childimmunization     No
Jyothi  1       one     childgender           F
Chikku  1       one     childimmunization     No
Chikku  1       one     childgender           M
```

Comment: Seems like a valid query. What is the question?

Comment: I need equivalent Criteria query for above SQL query ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent Criteria query for below SQL query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560161/equivalent-criteria-query-for-below-sql-query)

Comment: There is no reason to post the same question twice, not to mention thrice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Hibernate DetachedCriteria to express a subquery. [This Hibernate doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries) will give you a good idea about the topic.

Here is how you can write your SQL query by using Hibernate Criteria/DetachedCriteria:

```
//creates a DetachedCriteria
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Details.class);

//restrictions for the sub query
dc.add(Restrictions.like("question", "childgender"));
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("answer", "M"));
dc.add(Restrictions.eq("test", "1"));

//this is what your sub query will return
dc.setProjection(Projections.property("subject"));

//Criteria for Details.class
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(
            Details.class);

//restriction on your Criteria
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("question", "childimmunization"));

//you can add sub queries to your criteria as this
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("subject", dc));

// and this is result "answer"
criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("answer"));

List list = criteria.list();
```