# Get all parents that do not have specific child and sort them

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-criteria

I am having trouble formulating the following query. I have a `Parent.class` and `Child.class`. Each parent can have many children and each child can have many parents, so it is a bi-directional many-to-many association.

I need to get all parents that do not have specific child and sort them by some property, eg. `parent.age`.

The answer with most upvotes in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720502/hibernate-criteria-joining-table-without-a-mapped-association) question looks like it could be adapted to fit my problem, but it is said in the comments that when using sub-queries it is not possible to sort by `Parent` property.

Ideally I would like to achieve it with Criteria, but HQL would be OK too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct p from Parent p, Child c 
where c.id = :childId
and c not member of p.children
order by p.age
```