# How can I join entities with criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two entity classes which don't contain any association in their mappings.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mailing", name = "recipient_code_statistics")
public class RecipientCodeStatistics {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "recipient_code_id", unique = true)
    private long recipientCodeId;

    //GET, SET
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "mailing", name = "recipient_code")
public class RecipientCode {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    //GET ,SET
}
```

Is it possible to write a `criteria` query, similar to the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM recipient_code_statistic 
LEFT OUTER JOIN recipient_code
ON recipient_code_statistic.recipient_code_id = recipient_code.id
WHERE recipient_code.code = '123'
```

Whitout declaring association with `@OneToMany` annotation in the mapping explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to write an explicit join without mapping the two entity objects. But you could do a subquery.

[Here is a reference to a similiar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/720502/2248239)

[And here the link to the answer containing a subquery example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2102080/2248239)

Answer (score 1):

try using a native query @NativeQuery()

Comment: NativeQuery looks as I should write sql-query. But I'm interested in a criteria-like solution.