# Joining tables without relation using JPA criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables with no modeled relation:

Table `comm` with columns:

```
name
date
code
```

Table `persondesc` with columns:

```
code
description
```

Relationship between the two tables is many to one (many **comm** to one **persondesc**):

**com.code = persondesc.code**

These two tables are mapped with annotations but I have no relation declared.

What I'm trying to is to select `comm` table ordered by `persondesc.description`.

How can I do this JPA and Hibernate?

Comment: what is "Hibernate criteria" and "using hibernate" relevance here? are you not using the JPA API?

Comment: chsdk - it's not the same question. in my question two object/tables are mapped in the Java annotations in Snukker question one of the object/tables or are not mapped at all "not mapped in the Java annotations or xml."

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720502/hibernate-criteria-joining-table-without-a-mapped-association/76720561#76720561

Answer (score 44):

So if your classes have no "relation", then you do a query like

```
SELECT a FROM A a
CROSS JOIN B b
WHERE a.someField = b.otherField
ORDER BY b.anotherField
```

Which can be achieved using JPA Criteria, *something like*

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = emf.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<A> query = cb.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> aRoot = query.from(A.class);
Root<B> bRoot = query.from(B.class);
aRoot.alias("a");
bRoot.alias("b");

query.select(aRoot)
  .where(cb.equal(aRoot.get(A_.someField), bRoot.get(B_.otherField))
  .orderBy(cb.asc(bRoot.get(B_.anotherField)));
```

... Or just redesign your classes and do your developers a favour.

Comment: Do those `.alias()` matter?

Comment: they matter if your JPA provider uses them in the generated SQL so that it is more readable. But then you may be unlucky and have a JPA provider that does what it feels like and creates ugly names in the SQL

Comment: @Neil Stockton _"... Or just redesign your classes and do your developers a favour."_ What if you have a base module that contains common entities and then someone writes a module that uses the common entities and also contains entity extension classes, e.g. `CommonEntity` and `CommonEntityDimensionData`. Assuming that `CommonEntity` can not be modified it does not know about the extension class.

Comment: Where do 'A_' and 'B_' come from. When I try this, I get "Cannot resolve symbol 'A_'"

Comment: @slashdottir it's metamodel https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/metamodel.html#metamodel-static

Comment: How would you do this if I wanted an outer join?

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate 5.1 introduced explicit joins on unrelated entities for [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Persistence_Query_Language). So now you can just write a `JOIN` like native SQL:

```
List<Comm> results = entityManager
  .createQuery("""
    SELECT c FROM Comm c
     JOIN PersonDesc pd ON c.code = pd.code
     ORDER BY pd.description""", Comm.class)
  .getResultList();
```

Click [here](https://thorben-janssen.com/how-to-join-unrelated-entities/) for more detailed example.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest solution is to create view.
Then create an Entity class for that view and execute query against view.

**View:**

```
create or replace view view_comm_persondesc as select c.name, c.date, c.code, p.description from comm c inner join persondesc p on c.code = p.code;
```

**Code**

```
@Entity(name = "view_comm_persondesc")
public class ViewCommPerson{ 
    @Id
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private Date date; 
    private String description;

    ... All Getters/Setters ...

}



    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ViewCommPerson> query = cb.createQuery(ViewCommPerson.class);
    Root<ViewCommPerson> root = query.from(ViewCommPerson.class);
    // You can add your filter here
    List<ViewCommPerson> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Hope it servers your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using Subquery. Example with 'like' operation on persondesc.description

```
Subquery<persondesc> subquery = query.subquery(persondesc.class);
Root<persondesc> subRoot = subquery.from(persondesc.class);
subquery.select(subRoot.get("code"));

Predicate likeDescriptionPr = cr.like(subRoot.get("name"), "%" + searchTerm + "%")
subquery.where(likeDescriptionPr);
Predicate joinPredicate = cr.in(root.get("code")).value(subquery);
```