# How to join two or more not association entity like as sql joined with on condition

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have entity class, those classes not association but have common property (ex. Serial no). I don't want to write association for tables. I want joined tables like SQL join condition. How do I write criteria query for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Criteria query can be use only if there is an association. You can use HQL if there is no association but still want to join. Still the below link

[Hibernate criteria: Joining table without a mapped association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720502/hibernate-criteria-joining-table-without-a-mapped-association)

Comment: Thank you. But i known jpa allow this. What is your opinion.